# Error test upload php unit symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload, phpunit

Im following the tutorial from symfony's website to make my phpunit's test for my controller.

Im trying to test an upload on a form and i have 3 fields on this form : title,description and file.

I use :

```
public function testScenarioAdd() {

    $client = static::createClient();

     $x_wsse = 'UsernameToken Username="username@fai.fr", PasswordDigest="aeirugbjcUbfmùJK", Nonce="OTMzOGMwYzFkYTk2MzJmYzBh", Created="2013-11-12T10:22:15+01:00"';
    //X_Wsse is for the connection systeme on my application.

    $image = new UploadedFile(
        '/past/to/your/images.jpg',
        'images.jpg',
        'image/jpeg',
        100000
    );

    $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/ad/create', array('ad_form' => array('title' => 'test', 'description' => 'Test description')),array(), array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_X-WSSE' => $x_wsse));

    $response = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
    $json_response = json_decode($response);
    print_r($response);
}
```

When i launch it I have an error saying : 
{"app_error":{"success":500,"result":[{"message":"Array to string conversion",...

Am i doing something wrong ? or missing something in my code ?

Thanks for your help :)

Edit :

Thanks but, what ive done there is working on another test without upload, i still tried it and its not working. I still have the error array to string... I think it come from the fonction UplaodedFile or maybe from my controller itself because when i try the other solution from symfony's web site with

`$photo = array(
    'tmp_name' => '/path/to/photo.jpg',
    'name' => 'photo.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'size' => 123,
    'error' => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
);`

With putting the

`$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/ad/create', array('ad_form[title]' => 'test', ad_form[description] => 'test description'),array('file' => $image),array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_X-WSSE' => $x_wsse));`

The important part of my controller is :

```
            if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $Ad->preCreate();
                $odm->persist($Ad);
                $odm->flush();
                $odm->clear();

                $data = $this->listAction($request, 1, 5);
                Tags::setEvent($request, $this->container, 'member.create.ad', $user->getId(), $Ad->getId());

                return $data;

            } else {
                $data = Errors::formatJson($form, $this->container);
            }
        }
    }

    return new JsonResponse(array('ad_create' => $data));
```

Im kinda new in symfony, i really dont know where this error can come from...

Answer (score 0):

Client::Request method expects you to provide it with one-dimensional array of data. So try this code:

```
<?php
//...
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/ad/create', 
    array('ad_form[title]' => 'test', 
          'ad_form[description]' => 'Test description'),
    array(), 
    array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'HTTP_X-WSSE' => $x_wsse));
```

Comment: I found out where the problem came from : $form->bind($request); But i still dont know what's wrong... Any idea

Comment: replace `array('file' => $image)` with `array('ad_form[file]' => $image)`. And also UploadedFile object should be created with `test=true` `$image = new UploadedFile(
        '/past/to/your/images.jpg',
        'images.jpg',
        'image/jpeg',
        100000, null, true
    );`

Comment: I forgot to answer ;) But yeah the problem came from the "array('file' => $image) with array('ad_form[file]' => $image)" thanks a lot !